# Z3 python - Return constraint that holds True

Tags: python, python-3.x, z3, z3py

I create list of  `bool` xs, one of these is `True`

```
# b is a random number
xs= [Bool("xs{i}".format(i)) for i in range(0,b)]
# only one is True
s.add(PbEq([(x,1) for x in xs], 1))
if s.check() == sat:
m = s.model()
```

How can I return only the constraint that holds `True` value? I processed it as a list of strings. But, I think converted to a list of strings not logical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over `xs` and evaluate:

```py
from z3 import *

b = 10
xs = [Bool("xs_%d" % i) for i in range(0,b)]

s = Solver()
s.add(PbEq([(x,1) for x in xs], 1))

if s.check() == sat:
   m = s.model()
   for x in xs:
       if(m.eval(x)):
           print("%s is true" % x)
       else:
           print("%s is false" % x)
```

When I run this, it prints:

```
xs_0 is true
xs_1 is false
xs_2 is false
xs_3 is false
xs_4 is false
xs_5 is false
xs_6 is false
xs_7 is false
xs_8 is false
xs_9 is false
```